# Calling onchange method on product from values

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I created invoice already and now I want to create invoice lines. but first, I want to call _onchange_product_id() method on the product that I'm adding to account_inv_line that I would receive all values from that product. how can I do this?  `onchange_inv_line_fields` always returns `None`

```py
 for key, value in csv_info.iteritems():
            account_invoice = {
                'partner_id': value['partner_id'],
                'number': value['number'],
                'date_invoice': value['date_invoice'],
            }
            invocie = acc_inv_obj.with_context(type='in_invoice').create(account_invoice)
        for value_line in csv_info[key]['invoice_line']:
            account_inv_line = {
                'product_id': value_line['product_id'],
                'price_unit': value_line['price_unit'],
                'quantity': value_line['quantity'],


            }
                inv_line = self.env['account.invoice.line'].create(account_inv_line)
                onchange_inv_line_fields = inv_line._onchange_product_id()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call onchange method we need to create temp_lines like this:

```py
temp_line = self.env['account.invoice.line'].new(account_inv_line)
temp_line._onchange_product_id()                
account_inv_line.update(temp_line._convert_to_write(temp_line._cache))
invocie.invoice_line_ids.create(account_inv_line)
```